# Проблема с ajax

Tags: ajax, php, html, javascript

Есть два файла `urlpost.php`, `ajax.html`.
Проблема в том, что  в urlpost.php, должно что-то находится в `POST['url']`, а там нет нечего.

файл ajax.html

---

```
params = "url = oreilly.com" 
request = new ajaxRequest()
request.open("POST", "urlpost.php", true) 
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
request.onreadystatechange = function () {  
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200) {

            if (this.responseText != null) { 
                document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = this.responseText
                document.write = this.responseText              
              alert('Все ок')
            }
            else alert("Ошибка ajax Данные не получены")

        }
        else alert("Ошибка ajax: " + this.statusText)
    }
}

 request.send(params) 
function ajaxRequest() {
    try {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    catch (e1) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        }
        catch (e2) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }
            catch (e3) {
                request = false
            }
        }
    }
    return request
}
```

Файл `urlpost.php`.

---

```
   <?php
  echo 'fdsafda';
  echo file_get_contents("http://".$_POST['url']);

    ?>
```

Воводит только 'fdsafda'; и пишет

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: operation failed in Y:homelocalhostwwwurlpost.php on line 4

Comment: это помарка

Comment: что, если этот тестовый пример IE открыть?))где же их любимые ActiveXObject и Microsoft.XMLHTTP....да, это определённо мат.часть...
________
Было написано создается объект, естественно через кроссбраузерную функция. Спецально для тебя добавил

Comment: ладно, уговорил

Comment: @LeD4eG - походу я гавно программист :*(

Везде всегда писал условие(если ручками писал ajax) вида `this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200`. Все что > 200 - специфично и обычно(читай в 99% случаев) не используется. Писать проверку статусов вида `(status >= 200 && status < 300) || status == 304` целесообразно только при написании библиотеки или чего0либо подобного. Ваши знания http в данном случае неуместны.

А вот что касаеться microsoft и всего остального что вы написали - это вообще полный бред(даже улыбнуло), вообще-то я имел введу [КАГБЫ](http://hashcode.ru/).

Comment: @AlexWindHope - с Вами уж точно спорить не собираюсь. Ваши слова для меня авторитетны. раз Вы так говорите - я прислушаюсь. спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Первое что бросается в глаза `"url = oreilly.com"`, по-моему параметры не должны разделяться пробелами, то есть должно быть что-то вроде `'url=someurl.com'`
2. Вторым делом следует проверить, а отсылается ли вообще этот запрос на сервер? То есть открыть например страничку с ajax в google chrome и там открыть средства разработчика, там открыть вкладку сеть и там можно посмотреть полностью запрос, какие параметры были отправлены, что пришло от сервера.
3. Во избежании проблем с различными браузерами желательно использоваться для ajax какие нибудь популярные javascript фреймворки (например jQuery), что бы можно было удобно писать код под любой браузер

попробуйте сделать 2-ой пункт) наверняка сразу поймете в чем ошибка

Comment: О да, именно с такими знаниями человек готов использовать JQuery...

Comment: на мой взгляд разобраться и написать аякс на jQuery написать куда проще, нежели писать или копипастить откуда-то непонятный аля-кроссбраузерный код

Comment: спс все было из-за "url = oreilly.com", там в книге просто шрифт тупой, и запятую от точки не отличишь, тире от равно

Comment: @ice178 - вот в том то и суть - для вас это, цитирую, "аля-кроссбраузерный код", хотя здесь все абсолютно элементарно.

И, кагбы намекну - инициализация XMLHttpRequest объекта в jquery(как и в других поп.фреймворках) реализована примерно таким-же образом. Не верите? ->> в исходники (хотя там намного больше нипанатного :D)

@Zow - надо было сразу написать что ты читаешь книгу...

PS: тебе пока рано jquery :)

Comment: @AlexWindHop я читаю Никсона. все что читал, понял. Теперь там раздел Аякс. Хотя в его книги о ДжаваСкрипт ваще очень мало, что написанно, в основном о PHP

Comment: @Zow - по javascript лучшая книга для начала "Javascript - подробное руководство", потом ютуб + запрос в поиск "javascript crockford"(если английский хоть немного знаешь).
****
Книга по JS ищется в гугле по запросу "книга с носорогом" :DDD

Comment: to AlexWindHope
1. 3ий пункт из моего ответа был озвучен всего лишь в качестве рекомендации, не стоит так цепляться.
2. Прекрасно себе представляю как выглядит инициализация XMLHttpRequest объекта в jquery и даже не буду спорить что она будет выглядеть примерно так же
3. но на мой взгляд даже для человека не очень знакомого с javascript элементарная работа с dom и ajax будет проще через jQuery.

Comment: Вообще-то я не писал нигде что JQuery это сложно, LOL - нет, JQuery это очень просто(порой даже через чур), но за все надо платить.
****
Как-раз таки я согласен, что человек не очень знакомый с javascript, может использовать JQuery(если быть точным практически с 0-евыми знаниями).

Если речь идет о фрилансе или *реальной работе* с *сжатыми сроками* - несомненно я только за использования надежного инструмента коим является JQuery(*и не только он*).

Здесь же речь идет об обучении. И да - а если вы будете писать на nodejs? Или будете писать код вне браузера? Сильно вам поможет JQuery?